# On the Y-Combinator in Lambda Calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus

I am trying to follow [this](http://hisham.hm/2011/04/04/understanding-at-last-the-y-combinator-a-programmer-friendly-perspective/) explanation on the Y-combinator

Fairly at the beginning the author shows this function definition and claims that `stepper(stepper(stepper(stepper(stepper()))) (5)` were equal to factorial(5).

```
stepper = function(next_step)
             return function(n)
                       if n == 0 then
                          return 1
                       else
                          return n * next_step(n-1)
                       end
                    end
          end
```

I have translated this into (enriched) lambda syntax to the best of my understanding as follows:
$\renewcommand{\l}{\lambda} \renewcommand{\t}{\text}$

for $2!$

$((\l f. \l n.\ (\t{zero})\ \overline{n}\ \overline{1}\ \overline{n} \times f\ (\overline{n} - 1))\ (\l f. \l n.\ (\t{zero})\ \overline{n}\ \overline{1}\ \overline{n} \times f\ (\overline{n} - 1)))\ \overline{2}$
$\longrightarrow (\l n.\ (\t{zero})\ \overline{n}\ \overline{1}\ \overline{n} \times (\l f. \l n.\ (\t{zero})\ \overline{n}\ \overline{1}\ \overline{n} \times f\ (\overline{n} - \overline{1}))\ (\overline{n} - 1))\ \overline{2}\ $
$\longrightarrow (\t{zero})\ \overline{2}\ \overline{1}\ \overline{n} \times (\l f. \l n.\ (\t{zero})\ n\ \overline{1}\ \overline{n} \times f\ (\overline{n} - 1))\ (\overline{2} - \overline{1}) $
$\longrightarrow \overline{n} \times (\l f. \l n.\ (\t{zero})\ \overline{n}\ \overline{1}\ \overline{n} \times f\ (\overline{n} - \overline{1}))\ (\overline{2} - \overline{1}) $

Here is the problem now. If I apply $(\overline{2} - \overline{1})$ now it gets inserted into $f$, which makes no sense. So, should the call

`stepper(stepper(stepper(stepper(stepper()))) (5)`

not also have an initial argument for the innermost `stepper()`-call? The author claims the code to work correctly, so what am I missing here, please?

Comment: The main things to "understand" about Y combinator is that there is a lambda expression $Y$ such that for every lambda expression $F$, that $YF$ is a fixed point of $F$, that is $F(YF) = YF$.  There are several lambda expressions $Y$ that have this property, it is usually easier to express them in terms of combinators.  It can be pretty complicated when you try to follow reasoning on how to find a $Y$ expression, but once you've found it, the important thing is to be able to verify the fixed point property, which is just a straightforward evaluation of $F(YF)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, assuming that $n$ will reach $0$ while we get to the innermost `stepper` function, that would allow us to input anything as `next_step` is not used then. (Probably `nil` is passed this way to the function.)

Now `stepper()` is a function that basically expects the input `0` and returns `1`.

The next step is `stepper(stepper())` which inputs `n` and returns `n * stepper()(n-1)`, i.e. if `n` happens to be `1` now, it returns `1`.

Following this logic, the given 5-fold `stepper` function seems to expect the input `4`, so there is a mistake in any case. Maybe `if n==1` was rather meant, or just missed one more `stepper`.

Indeed, it would be clearer if e.g. this innermost input would be something like $\lambda x.1$.